# How to enqueue elements to a queue and then dequeue them?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2

Imports and implicits for the following snippets:

```scala
import cats.effect.{ConcurrentEffect, ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ec)
implicit val c: ConcurrentEffect[IO] = IO.ioConcurrentEffect
implicit val t: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ec)
```

The goal is to add the integers 1 to 3 to a fs2 `Queue` and then dequeue them. The first attempt:

```scala
val s1 = for {
  q <- Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]) // Create unbounded queue that terminates when it gets None
  _ <- Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue) // Enqueue 1 to 3
  _ <- Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None)) // Terminate queue
  outStream <- q.dequeue // Get dequeue stream
} yield outStream

s1.compile.toList.unsafeRunSync()
```

This returns `List(1)`. Not sure why.

Second attempt:

```
val s2 = for {
  q <- Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]) // Create unbounded queue that terminates when it gets None
  _ <- Stream(
    Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue), // Enqueue 1 to 3
    Stream.sleep(1.seconds) >> Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None)) // Wait 1 second and terminate stream
  ).parJoin(2) // Run both streams in parallel
  outStream <- q.dequeue // Get dequeue stream
} yield outStream 

s2.compile.toList.unsafeRunSync()
```

This returns `List(1,2)`. Also not sure why.

Why these examples returned what they returned? What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look what you actually defined here:

```
val s1 = for {
  q <- Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int])
  _ <- Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue)
  _ <- Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None))
  outStream <- q.dequeue // Get dequeue stream
} yield outStream
```

this is the same as

```
Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]).flatMap { q =>

  Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue).flatMap { _ =>

    Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None)).flatMap { _ =>
      q.dequeue
    }
  }
}
```

- you create a queue in `Stream`
- then for each element of this stream (for each `Queue`) you enqueue 3 `Some` elements - lazily meaning that until this element is needed the side-effect is not evaluated
- *then for for each enque you also put `None` into queue*
- you basically created a stream of `Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3), None` before you got to the dequeue part! And since it is none terminated Queue it stops after the first `None`, so you end up with `Stream(1)` evaluated to `List(1)`

Meanwhile with second example you have

```
val s2 = for {
  q <- Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]) 
  _ <- Stream(
    Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue), 
    Stream.sleep(1.seconds) >> Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None)) 
  ).parJoin(2) 
  outStream <- q.dequeue 
} yield outStream
```

which is equal to

```
Stream.eval(Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]).flatMap { q =>

  Stream(
    Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(q.enqueue), 
    Stream.sleep(1.seconds) >> Stream.eval(q.enqueue1(None)) 
  ).parJoin(2).flatMap { _ =>
    q.dequeue 
  }
}
```

- you create a queue in `Stream`
- then for each element of this stream (for each `Queue`) you create a smaller Stream

  - you are enqueuing `Some` 1, 2, 3 *lazily* in one stream
  - you enqueue `None` an another
  - you non-deterministically combine both streams, so you don't have a strong guarantees when sequence of `Some` will be interrupted by `None`, in your tests the circumstances made it so that it happened after evaluating 2 elements of the first stream

You basic error is using `Stream[IO, *]` and `IO` interchangably: when you make a `flatMap` on `Stream` the next line is NOT evaluated after all elements of the previous line has been evaluated, but after every single element of the previous line has been evaluated. After all `Stream` is (lazy, side-effecting) collection so in for-comprehension it behaves more like a (`Lazy`)`List` when it comes to order of operations.

If you didn't evaluate everything is `Stream` it would work as you expect:

```
val createQueue: IO[NoneTerminatedQueue[IO, Int]] = Queue.noneTerminated[IO, Int]

def enqueueValues(queue: NoneTerminatedQueue[IO, Int]) =
  Stream(1,2,3).map(Some(_)).through(queue.enqueue) ++ Stream.eval(queue.enqueue1(None))

def dequeueValues(queue: NoneTerminatedQueue[IO, Int]) =
  queue.dequeue

// these are IO, not Stream[IO, *] !!!
val io = for {
  queue <- createQueue
  _ <- enqueueValues(queue).compile.drain.start
  result <- dequeueValues(queue).compile.toList
} yield result

io.runUnsafeSync
```